# cruisecontrol.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cruisecontrol.rb

we are using cruisecontrol.rb for CI.
but cruise control is failing with this output

```
  /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.6-20090610/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:258:in     `activate': can't activate activesupport (= 1.4.2, runtime) for [], already activated activesupport-2.2.2 for ["rails-2.2.2"] (Gem::Exception) from /opt/ruby-enterprise-
```

can anybody trouble shoot.

I want to run rake task and rcov can anyone suggest rake task for it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is a typical *rubygems* gem version conflict

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have different versions of rails (or at least those gems) on your box and it's getting confused between them.